# Compactar arquivos em partes independentes ( sem necessidade de estarem justas para descompactar)

Tags: java, arquivo-zip

Na minha aplicação eu consigo compactar uma pasta e seu conteúdo, este conteúdo é resultado de manipulação de pdf, jpg e xls. Porém eu precisava dividir em partes ( o arquivo compactado não pode ser maior que por exemplo 10 MB), mas de forma que uma parte possa ser extraída sem a necessidade da outra. Consigo também com uma outra classe compactar em partes mas com a necessidade de todas as partes estarem juntas para poder extrair. 
Esta classe é a que uso para criar um arquivo único.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class ZipCompress {
    public static void compress(String dirPath, String zipName,String path) {
        Path sourceDir = Paths.get(dirPath);
        String zipFileName = path+zipName.concat(".zip");
        try {
            ZipOutputStream outputStream = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFileName));
            Files.walkFileTree(sourceDir, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
                @Override
                public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attributes) {
                    try {
                        Path targetFile = sourceDir.relativize(file);
                        outputStream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(targetFile.toString()));
                        byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(file);
                        outputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                        outputStream.closeEntry();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }
            });
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Update:

Adicionei o método em que estou trabahando para primeiramente separar os arquivos a cada "x mb" para depois compactar as pastas individualmente. Ainda não consegui colocar em um loop em que a cada "x mb" seja criada uma nova pasta e os arquivos então sejam copiados para esta nova pasta.

Outro detalhe é que percebi que chega a 10 MB meu método para de copiar os arquivos mesmo que está sendo usado `if (fileSizeInMB > 5)`, deveria da forma em que está, copiar todos.(Resolvido mudando de :`if (fileSizeInMB > 5)` para `if (fileSizeInMB >= 5)`, método atualizado na questão.

Update:

Resolvido para listar os arquivos da pasta ( pasta que conté os arquivos que desejo compactar), após isto criar uma nova pasta e mover os arquivos até que o tamanho acumulado seja "x MB", a cada vez que tamanho acumulado dos arquivos for maior que "x mb" criar uma nova pasta e mover os arquivos para esta nova pasta. O código pode certamente ser melhorado, aceito sugestões críticas.

```
public void listNovo() throws IOException {
File directory = new File("D:\\Faturas\\Gerados\\");
String pasta = "\\Pasta";
long length = 0;
long fileSizeInBytes = 0;
long fileSizeInMB = 0;
long fileSizeInKB = 0;
int count = 0;

File[] files = directory.listFiles();
for (File file : directory.listFiles()) {
    String fileName1 = file.getName();
    if (file.isFile()) {
        length += file.length();
        System.out.println("file:" + file.getName());
        fileSizeInBytes = length;
        fileSizeInKB = fileSizeInBytes / 1024;
        fileSizeInMB = fileSizeInKB / 1024;
        System.out.println("fileSizeInMB:" + fileSizeInMB);
        if (fileSizeInMB < 5) {
            File diretorio = new File(jTCaminho.getText() + pasta + count);
            if (!diretorio.exists()) {
                new File(jTCaminho.getText() + pasta + count).mkdir();
                Files.move(file.toPath(), Paths.get(diretorio.toString(), fileName1), REPLACE_EXISTING);
                length += fileSizeInMB;
            }
            else if (diretorio.exists()) {
                Files.move(file.toPath(), Paths.get(diretorio.toString(), fileName1), REPLACE_EXISTING);
                length += fileSizeInMB;
            }
        }

        if (fileSizeInMB >= 5) {
            fileSizeInMB = 0;
            length=0;
               count++;
            if (fileSizeInMB < 5) {
                File diretorio = new File(jTCaminho.getText() + pasta + count);
                if (!diretorio.exists()) {
                    new File(jTCaminho.getText() + pasta + count).mkdir();
                    Files.move(file.toPath(), Paths.get(diretorio.toString(), fileName1), REPLACE_EXISTING);
                    length += fileSizeInMB;
                }
               else if (diretorio.exists()) {
                    Files.move(file.toPath(), Paths.get(diretorio.toString(), fileName1), REPLACE_EXISTING);
                    length += fileSizeInMB;
                }
            }
        }
    }//fim isFile
}//fim directoryListfile
```

}

Comment: Tenho quase certeza que não dá. Para conseguir o que quer, crie arquivos zip diferentes. Como os arquivos jpg e pdf já usam compactação (não tenho certeza quanto aos xls) a compactação será muito pequena e não é difícil estimar o tamanho do arquivo compactado. Você seleciona uns 9 MB de arquivos e compacta. Ou então experimente usar o utilitário tar, pode ser que ele atenda sua necessidade.

Comment: @Piovezan na verdade a dúvida é sobre compactar em partes independentes, sem a necessidade de ter depois todas  as partes juntas para poder descompactar. Já parti pra uma abordagem onde eu verifico o tamanho acumulado dos arquivos e, quando chega a 10 MB eu crio outra pasta,e começo a adicionar os arquivos restantes nesta outra pasta. Obrigado pela ajuda, daqui a pocuo posto o novo código parcial que estou trabalhando.

Comment: Foi sobre isso que falei.

Comment: @Piovezan adicionei o código em que estou trabalhando no momento.